# What is the Best Practice for adding user to AWS database after signup using Okta

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs, auth0, okta

I am trying to use auth as a service. I am wondering what the best fault-tolerant practices are to add a user to a database after signup using Okta/Auth0/Cognito.

A potential solution I have, is that once a user gets added I then add to an SQS queue a request to insert the user into the database. The only problem with that is that login would then have to not only sign-in with okta every time but I would also have to check that the user exists? I can't think of a problem with that but there could be extra error handling.

Any guidance would be helpful.